# Recursion: How to avoid returning before all paths are completed

Tags: java, recursion

This can apply to any language really but I'm using Java. This seems so simple but I been programming many hours straight now and my brain is fried and I'm just missing something simple I think. See example below. In the `populateArray()` method below, there is a return call (see the comment) but will that cause the parent method to return prematurely (before all recursion is completed and the `mListUrls` is fully populated) ?

```
public ArrayList<String> startMethod( String s){

    mString = s;

    Node startNode = getNode(mString );

    populateArray(startNode, 0 );

    return mListValues;

}

private void populateArray(Node node, int i{

    if(i == 100 ){
        mListValues.add(node.value);

        //I do want to continue here, but will returning here return the startMethod() above prematurely,
        //before all recursion is completed?
        return;
    }

    if(node.first() != null){
        populateArray(node.first(), i + 1);
    }

    if(node.second() != null){
        populateArray(node.second(), i + 1);
    }

    if(node.third() != null){
        populateArray(node.third(), i + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, a return statement only returns to the calling code... which *could* be `startMethod`, but could equally be another `populateArray` call. Have you tried debugging through your code carefully to see what happens? (The check for i being exactly 100 seems very odd, mind you... what are you intending to achieve?)

Comment: This is just example code to demonstrate my question in principle.

Comment: Recursion is rarely a good solution.  Iteration is often a simpler (and better) option.

Comment: @DwB I found recursion so elegant :(

Answer (score 0):

The recursion comes into play when populateArray calls itself, populateArray. When any call returns, it only returns to its parent which may be populateArray, or some other function. Think of a stack of calls, any return only pops the top off. It doesn't return ALL the way back to the base. The parent can decide what do do then. It can decide any number of things, call something else, recurse again, or return to *its* parent (the grandparent), which could very well cascade all the way to the root, but not necessarily.